# bar graph in vb.net using data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have created a private sub name graphloaddata and call it in `MyBase.Load`. What I want it to happen is I want the user to load data from specified date between from date to a certain date but what I get when I run my code it just simply added new graph details at the end. I want it to display only data from that specified date. How can I achieve this?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient    
Public Class graph

    Dim dbconn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim dbcomm As MySqlCommand
    Dim dbread As MySqlDataReader


    Private Sub graph_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        graphLoadData()
    End Sub
    Private Sub graphLoadData()
        dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;user id=root; database=sample;")

        Try
            dbconn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error in connection, please check Database and connection server.")
        End Try
        Dim sql As String

        Try

            Chart1.Series.Add("Department")
            sql = "select count(u.idno), deptName from utilization u right join student s on u.idno = s.idno right join course c on c.course_id= s.course_id right join department d on c.deptID = d.deptID  group by deptName " '= '" & month & "' 
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            While dbread.Read
                Chart1.Series("Department").Points.AddXY(dbread("deptName").ToString, dbread("Count(u.idno)").ToString)
            End While
            dbread.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
            dbread.Close()
            Exit Sub
        Finally
            dbread.Close()
            dbconn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub view_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles view.Click
        dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;user id=root;database=sample;")

        Try
            dbconn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error in connection, please check Database and connection server.")
        End Try
        Dim sql As String
        'Dim month As String = graphDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("MMMM")
        'MsgBox(month)
        Try

            Chart1.Series.Add("Specific")
            sql = "select count(u.idno), deptName from utilization u join student s on u.idno = s.idno join course c on c.course_id= s.course_id join department d on c.deptID = d.deptID where date between '" + Format(fromdate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + Format(todate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' group by deptName " '= '" & month & "' 
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            While dbread.Read
                Chart1.Series("Department").Points.AddXY(dbread("deptName").ToString, dbread("Count(u.idno)").ToString)
            End While
            dbread.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
            dbread.Close()
            Exit Sub
        Finally
            dbread.Close()
            dbconn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[MyBase.Load image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvmQA.png)

[After clicking view button something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqaGV.png)

Comment: Chart1.Series.Add("Specific") - should be "Department"? Or maybe it should not be at all?

Comment: yeah, I change it now to "Department" but it give an error message,"A chart element with the name Department already exist in the series collection" everytime I click the view button

Comment: So it should not be at all...

Comment: What do you mean by that? meaning, I have to delete that line? or inside that Chart1.Series.Add("Specific") make it to empty? is that what you mean?